# How can I create a frame and open two files split vertically in it?

Tags: frames, window-splitting

I am trying to write an Elisp function that will create a new frame and in that new frame open two files split vertically.

I have been unable to find anything about this in the Elisp manual, node [Creating Frames](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html)

How can I do this?

Comment: When you say "split vertically" do you mean that the frame is split into two windows side-by-side or one above the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function:

```
(defun my/open-files-vert-in-new-frame (file1 file2)
  (interactive "f\nf")
  (select-frame-set-input-focus (make-frame))
  (find-file file1)
  (split-window-below)
  (find-file file2))
```

The key is `select-frame-set-input-focus` which makes subsequent functions operating on windows of the new frame and set input focus on it.